# Is HttpWebRequest.GetResponse required to complete a POST?

Tags: c#, .net, web, httpwebrequest

For POST requests using HttpWebRequest, when I write to a request stream, at what point does the data get sent? Is it when I close the request stream or when I call GetResponse? Is the GetResponse call required?

The .net documentation does not seem to be very clear about what is really happening

Here's the code I'm curious about:

```
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = jsonData.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/json";

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

requestStream.Write(jsonData, 0, jsonData.Length);

requestStream.Close();

var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to get the response *anyway* to read the status code and work out whether your `POST` was accepted or rejected by the server...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `GetResponse` call is must, not only for POST request but for GET, HEAD requests too. Request / data is sent at the point when you call `GetResponse`.

Comment: it is not true, I experience the request to be sent right after writing the data to its stream, the GetResponse is commented out and I am able to debug the remote called method. I am completely desperate...

Answer (score 2):

Start the sniffer and set breakpoint on your `requestStream.Close();` and you will see that request is making when `GetResponse()` called.